# How to hide and show the forms located in tab pages of tab control on selection basis in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using `TabControl` with two `TabPage's` in my Windows application. On `TabPage2` selection, need to show so many forms(nearly 12-15 forms) on button click in a zigzag manner(like form1, form2, form1, form3, form4, form1 one after another). On `TabPage` selection, need to hide the forms displayed in `TabPage2.` Again If I opened `TabPage2`, need to display the same form.

How to show and hide the forms on the basis of tab page selection? I tried the following code and is working fine. Is there any better way to implement the same functionality?
In main form button click,

```
public static Form1 form1obj; 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                        
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    frm.Show(this);            
    createObj(frm);           
}

public void createObj(Form1 frm)
{
    form1obj = frm;          
}

private void tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    if (tabControl.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["tabpage1"])
    {              
        if (form1obj != null && form1obj.Visible)
        {
            form1obj.Hide();
            bstep1obj = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
         if(bstep1obj)
         form1obj.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @StepUp: WinForms only.

Comment: Why do you need to show `form` in `TabItem`?

Comment: Set form1obj.Visible = true, instead of form1obj.Show();

Comment: @Chris: The above code is working fine. But I want any simplified approach because I have to implement the same for 12-15 forms

Comment: If the code works fine you might get a better response on the CodeReview StackExchange :-)

Comment: As a user, I would be returning any software that popped 12+ forms in my face simply because I clicked a tab.  I wonder how the user is going to find Tab #1 under all that mess?